# pass a list of dataframes into a loop to combine and change titles simultaneously

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a group of dfs with different titles that i need to bind row by row: I was hoping to change the names of the cols so that each one has the same titles.

df1

```
 name, score
 smith, 3
 smith, 7
 smith, 5
```

df2

```
 type, price
 food, 3
 food, 5
 food, 2.6
```

I want to combine this so that each one has the same titles and is combined by rows. I have 32 of these dataframes all with different titles so I plan to use a loop

I made a list of dfs

```
 groups <- c(df1, df2, df3, etc)
```

then tried to combine into an empty df:

```
 new_df <- data.frame(words=character(),numbers=numeric())

 for (i in 1:length(groups))
 {
 x <- data.frame(words=character(),numbers=numeric())
 x[,1] <- groups[i]
 x[,2] <- groups[i+1]
 new_df <- rbind(new_df, x)
 }
```

unfortunately it just returns an empty df with a bunch of warnings. Can anyone tell me how to correct this? I expected new_df to be;

```
 words, numbers
 smith, 3
 smith, 7
 smith, 5
 food, 3
 food, 5
 food, 2.6
```

I'm sure this is easy for anyone with a little more experience than myself. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are your 32 data.frames not all nicely together in a `list`? First catch them from the wild:

```
dfList <- mget(paste0("df", 1:32))
```

Then you can use `lapply`:

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, setNames, nm = c("words", "numbers"))
```

And at last you `rbind` them:

```
DF <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Comment: A this is perfect, i didn't know the function mget. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want `do.call` and `rbind.data.frame` to do this correctly. `do.call` calls a function and gives it a list of arguments, and the `rbind.data.frame` argument is `rbind` specifically for a data frame.

Note that this will only work if the variables `df1$words` and `df2$words` are not factors, or otherwise you will get issues with not having the right factor levels.

```
new.df <- do.call(what = rbind.data.frame,
                  args = list(df1,df2))
```

EDITED TO ADD: More generally, you've always wanted to use the `rbind()` function. You have been trying to use a loop but this is something that should be done by way of a function in R.

Also, as pointed out by [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg), `rbind()` will only work when your tables have the same variable names. A quick way to fix this might be to use `setNames()` on all of them to give them the same names.

```
list_of_dfs <- list(df1,df2,df...)
list_of_dfs <- lapply(X = list_of_dfs,
                      FUN = setNames,
                      nm = c("words","numbers"))
big.df <- do.call(what = rbind.data.frame,
                  args = list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: This won't work because OP has different column names.

Comment: Oops. I totally missed that. Will update the answer accordingly.